# Keep single \ while convert YAML to JSON

Tags: json, yaml

I want to convert YAML to JSON and keep the `\` character as unescaped, i.e.

YAML

```
key: \u0022value\u0022
```

to JSON

```
{"key": "\u0022value\u0022"}
```

Is it possible to do? Because it usually converts `\` from YAML to `\\` in JSON

Answer (score 0):

In a YAML plain (=unquoted) scalar, no escape sequences are processed. YAML also has double-quoted scalars that do process escape sequences, so these two lines are equivalent in YAML:

```yaml
key: \u0022value\u0022
key: "\\u0022value\\u0022"
```

JSON only supports double-quoted strings with escaping, so naturally the JSON equivalent to your original YAML is

```json
{
  "key": "\\u0022value\\u0022"
}
```

If JSON wouldn't escape your `\` characters, *it would change the semantics of the value* because they would be processed as unicode escape sequences, which they are not in the original YAML.

So the transformation you want to do is a *semantic transformation*: You want to replace a value with a different value. You can do this by taking any YAML implementation, load the input, **replace** the string value `\u0022value\u0022` with the string it would evaluate to if it were double-quoted, which would be `"value"` (the double quotes are part of the value and result from evaluating `\u0022`), then write it out via some JSON implementation.

Even then, most JSON emitters would probably emit this as

```json
{
  "key": "\"value\""
}
```

There is generally no way to force a JSON library to choose the unicode escape sequence instead of `\"`.

Comment: thank you for your reply.

I can use only single \ for unicode characters

So I solved the problem by substitution \\ to \